# Facing issue on installing Sitecore9.1

Tags: installation

Trying to install Sitecore9.1 But facing error.
Already checked that solr(7.2.1) is working with https.
Please confirm, can we use same license of sotecore 9.0 for sitecore 9.1

[image]

Comment: Try to start the service manually to see what message you get (error might be logged in the event viewer).

Comment: If the service fails to start manually, you can check the logs for further information. To do this, run "services.msc", right click the service in question and click Properties. Open the Index Worker folder using the "Path to executable" path as a guide. You should then be able to navigate to the IndexWorker Logs subfolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if solr url has "/" at the end of the url in your power shell script you are running to install Sitecore.

Yes you can use Sitecore 9.0 license to install Sitecore 9.01